# Why was my flag disputed?

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387961/3124333 answer as "not an answer". Shortly afterwards my flag was "disputed" by somebody (I do not have enough cred to be able to see who did it), which is fine. However, shortly after *that*, a user "nullability" posted as a comment the exact reason why I flagged the answer.

What happened? Was I wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The reviewers disagreed with you.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5139633)

You'd get one of three statuses based on what happens:

**Helpful**

- Post gets deleted at any point, either through a review task, by the OP, or by a moderator.
- Post receives enough recommend deletion votes in a review task, but has a positive score. Your flag is marked as helpful, but the post does not get deleted and instead a new automatic flag is raised for a moderator to look into it.
- The post gets edited through the review task (or for very low quality flags, an edit directly on the post will also trigger this regardless of the review task's state).

**Disputed**

- Reviewers say it looks good, or there is a combination of votes that causes it to be considered controversial. Either way, review did not cause a deletion of the post.

**Declined**

- A moderator actually looks at your flag and declines it.

Comment: All that I understand. The part that confuses me, is that someone commented with the exact same reason as why I flagged the answer, _that_ comment got 3 votes, and yet the answer is there?

Comment: Comments do not matter. Yes, there were two Recommend Deletion votes on it, and presumably they both selected that option which would have automatically upvoted that comment. But none of that matters. What matters is the three people who said it looks fine. That completed review and automatically marked your flag as disputed. That's how the system works.