# Is this more appropriate as a comment or is it an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I ran into the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27497/3942575) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27482/3942575):

> I have honestly no idea, but I would definitely first have a look at
>   the [LaTeX Web Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201433117). There a whole section about generating PDF
>   from LaTeX, including esoterica such as forms.

Having read the help pages, particularly [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), it appeared to me that this *answer* wasn't really an answer (perhaps better suited as a comment, if at all).  As such, I flagged it as:

> **it is not an answer**
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

However, the flag was **disputed**.

Could somebody please help me understand how was I wrong in flagging it?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262068/why-was-my-flag-disputed. I agree with your flag, but it looks like reviewers (or at least, a couple reviewers) didn't. Probably an error on their part, in my opinion.

Comment: This answer was posted during the private beta, [before the comment feature existed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/). It's still not an answer, but it was an acceptable post at the time.

Comment: It is much easier to see how people disputed your flag if you take out the "I have honestly no idea" preface. Still not sure it's a *good* answer, but it does seem to become an answer. At any rate, like Josh said, this is a very old answer, posted when the site was very different. It is also an old question; I'm not sure if it is even on-topic.