# NAA-flag was disputed

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051061/404623) as:

> it is not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

My flag was disputed and according to [Why was my flag disputed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262068/why-was-my-flag-disputed) this means that (at least?) three reviewers think that the answer looks fine. I don't understand how the answer "looks fine" as it repeats the same regular expression that the question asker already knows about and states in the original question and does not attempt to answer the question at all.

Are there review bots or any other reason that my flag would be "disputed"?

Comment: because it is an attempt at an answer, maybe just a bad one.  Please take a look at [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) to understand the usage of that flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was likely disputed because it looks like an answer, and realistically is one.  It's a bad answer, it doesn't give anything useful to the asker, but it's an answer: it says 'Here, do this'.  If I ask "Why is the sky blue?" and you say "Because of purple chickens", it's still an answer, as is "Because the sky is blue".  Both are silly and inane, but both are answers.

For that, VLQ is a better flag; even that might not survive, because it requires a bit more work to verify than the average VLQ flag (it requires looking at the question and understanding at least a bit of it).  Remember, the flags are being reviewed by random people - not necessarily people who have any expertise *at all* in the tag.

In my opinion, the best thing to do with that answer is simply a downvote.  A VLQ flag isn't a bad idea either, but without explanation it won't go anywhere, and I don't know that I think that is something I'd bother an 'other' flag with (though I'm sure many people would, and it wouldn't be wrong to do so - explain in the 'other' text box why you think it should be deleted, a mod is more likely to agree with you if the reasoning is clear.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will keep this in mind when I come across things like this.

Comment: Also consider adding a comment to the post you want to flag. That makes flags easier to evaluate and will give the poster a hint what's wrong. (Look at the post while it's there, I added one.)